# Extracting values using jq streaming

Tags: json, stream, jq

I am trying to extract the values from a top-level JSON object using streaming with `jq`. For the sake of illustration, this is what the data look like (the actual data are rather large, hence needing to use streaming):

```
{
        "empty": null,
        "name": "John Smith",
        "sex": "male",
        "age": 51,
        "hobbies": [
          "running",
          "kayaking",
          "camping",
          "foraging"
         ]
}
```

Without streaming it's easy to get what I need:

```
$ jq ".name" sample.json 
"John Smith"
$ jq ".age" sample.json 
51
$ jq ".hobbies" sample.json 
[
  "running",
  "kayaking",
  "camping",
  "foraging"
]
```

When I use streaming I can get the value for the `"hobbies"` key:

```
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "hobbies")))' <sample.json
["running","kayaking","camping","foraging"]
```

But using the analogous command for the `"name"` or `"age"` keys gives an empty result:

```
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "name")))' <sample.json
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "age")))' <sample.json
```

I suspect that this is because the value is a scalar. But I'm not sure that this is the reason and, even if I was, I'm not sure how to use that information.

I discovered the `debug` operation which seems to yield some light on the situation.

```
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "hobbies") | debug))' <sample.json
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies",0],"running"]]
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies",1],"kayaking"]]
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies",2],"camping"]]
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies",3],"foraging"]]
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies",3]]]
["running","kayaking","camping","foraging"]
["DEBUG:",[["hobbies"]]]
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "name") | debug))' <sample.json
["DEBUG:",[["name"],"John Smith"]]
$ jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "age") | debug))' <sample.json
["DEBUG:",[["age"],51]]
```

So it looks like these values are being selected, but they are just not making it through to the output.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how `1 | truncate_stream()` works before subsequently applying other filter expressions. The `truncate_stream()` prefixed with a non-zero integer is used to *remove* paths specified by the integer in the streamed result.

e.g.  if your original result produced the following`[path, value]` pairs

```bash
jq -cn --stream 'inputs' json
[["empty"],null]
[["name"],"John Smith"]
[["sex"],"male"]
[["age"],51]
[["hobbies",0],"running"]
[["hobbies",1],"kayaking"]
[["hobbies",2],"camping"]
[["hobbies",3],"foraging"]
[["hobbies",3]]
[["hobbies"]]
```

Truncation with `1` would remove the first element of each path provided. Those with the paths removed are completely discarded from the output

```bash
jq -cn --stream '1|truncate_stream(inputs)' json
[[0],"running"]
[[1],"kayaking"]
[[2],"camping"]
[[3],"foraging"]
[[3]]
```

Your original attempt worked because, the `select` expression was able to get the desired paths to `hobbies`, with the parent root key `hobbies` removed, retaining only a list of elements.

But the same doesn't work for `age`, as you cannot completely trim down the path away. Remove the `["age"]` entry would leave a result as `[[],51]` leaving only the value field.

```bash
jq -cn --stream 'inputs|select(.[0][0] == "age")' json
[["age"],51]
```

If a level is provided to the above expression, i.e. `1|..` the `age` path would be completely removed, making the `fromstream` not construct your object back.

So for simple scalars, simply extract away the value from the indices as below without needing to use truncate at all

```bash
jq -cn --stream 'inputs|select(.[0][0] == "age")[1]'
51
```

Comment: Thank you! This is precisely the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: Would it be possible to generalise this so that `jq` "does the right thing" depending on the type of the value. Specifically, if the value is a scalar then simply dump the value, but if it's an array or object then return those?

Comment: @enid569 I don't think such an option exists. But you could wait to see if there are better answers on that